# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - Outlook 2010 AddIn ContextualTab Button

Tags: outlook-addin

I am having trouble iterating through the list of selected attachments in my Outlook 2010 Addin Project.

Here is the ribbon1.xml

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <contextualTabs>
      <tabSet idMso="TabSetAttachments">
        <tab idMso="TabAttachments">
          <group label="DWOS" id="DWOSAttachmentGroup">
            <button id="btnSendToJobOrder"
                size="large"
                label="Send to Job/Order"
                getImage="GetButtonImage"
                onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabSet>
    </contextualTabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Here is my OnMyButtonClick event:

```
 Public Sub OnMyButtonClick(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Dim attachmentSelection As AttachmentSelection = TryCast(control.Context, AttachmentSelection) '<-- Error Here

    For Each attachment As Outlook.Attachment In attachmentSelection
        ' Do Something
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.